# Parameter satisfying martingale properties

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

We want to find $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(\theta^{S_n})_{n \geq 0 }$ is a martingale under the initial conditions that are stochastic process is a random walk with $P(S_{n+1} = k+2)=0.5$ and P(S_{n+1} = k-1) = 0.5. I am stuck on the algebraic manipulation which I suspect requires some conceptual knowledge to solve for the parameter $\theta$ which satisfies martingale properties.

We can set up the following $$E[\theta^{S_n+1}|F_n] = \frac{1}{2}\theta^{S_n+2}+\frac{1}{2}\theta^{S_n-1}$$

However, how may this simplify to $$=\theta^3-2\theta+1=0$$

Of course, the next idea is to find such an equations roots.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $\mathbb P(S_{n+1}=k+2\mid S_n=k)=\frac12$ and $\mathbb P(S_{n+1}=k-1\mid S_n=k)=\frac12$, where $S_n= \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$, the $X_i$ are i.i.d., and $\mathbb P(X_1=2)=\mathbb P(X_1=-1)=\frac12$?

Comment: Also, I think you mean $\theta^{S_{n+1}}$ and $\theta^{S_{n-1}}$.